# Is there a way to combine a datagrid with a vertical-style data grid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, datagrid

Here is what I would like to do (this is a winforms c# app developed in Visual Studio 2013)

For the purposes of this email, say I have a table with the following fields:

header: string
entry: string
memo: string
order:  int
data1: text
data2: int
level: string.

The "header" in the image below should contain the value of the header field.
The "entry" in the image below should contain the value of entry field.

The "memo", "order", "data1", and "data2" should contain those field names (not the values)
Row one where it says "(value of) level" should contain one column for each value.
The " " should be the values of the fields in that row (memo, order, data1, or data2).

I have a better explanation and example in the below image.  But it basically has the last three columns as a vertical grid but the first two as a regular grid, if that makes any sense.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks more like a hierarchical (tree) structure to me.

Answer (score 1):

if u want horizontal grid create datatable structure shown in Image.

it no need to use another grid

hope this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a PivotGridControl from DevExpress.